# create anchors in a page with the content of <h2></h2> in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

Well I have a html text string in a variable:

```
$html = "<h1>title</h1><h2>subtitle 1</h2> <h2>subtitle 2</h2>";
```

so I want to create anchors in each subtitle that has  with the same name and then print the html code to browser and also get the subtitles as an array.

I think is using regex.. please help.

Comment: You mean `<a name="foo" />` anchors to reference the elements via `#` in the URL? You can easily achieve this by giving the elements an `id` attribute. Also , if you are building this stringy yourself anyway, just build it correctly from the beginning. No need to apply regex afterwards, besides all the other evil that comes with applying regex to HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry if my english is not good enough.. but what I want to do is create an anchor for every <h2>Sub Title</h2> so the user can go to Sub Title by #Sub Title. In html the result should be <a name="Sub Title"><h2>Sub Title</h2> and also in server side have an array that stores all the anchor names, $anchors[0] = "Sub Title"

Comment: Why do you need the anchors at the server side? As I said, you can achieve the same effect with `<h2 id="sub_title">Sub Title</div>`. BUt you didn't comment an the important part of my comment: Do you create this HTML string yourself? Is so why don't you add the anchor or ID right from the start?

Comment: I'm sorry, well I have the HTML in a mysql table, but that html has not any anchor, so I want to create them in the fly using php before printing, but also saving them in an array to create a table of contents with links.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick for you:

```
$pattern = "|<h2>(.*)</h2>|U";
preg_match_all($pattern,$html,$matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $match)
    $html = str_replace($match, "<a name='".$match."' />".$match, $html);

$array_of_elements = $matches[1];
```

Just make sure that $html has the existing html before this code starts. Then it will have an `<a name='foo' />` added after this completes, and $array_of_elements will have the array of matching text values.